# Siri spells mnemonic like the disease pneumonic

Tags: iphone, siri

How do I get Siri to change her to spell it correctly?

Comment: I do not know if there is any way to train Siri like with some dictation software; however, if you pronounce them correctly, `nəˈmänik` instead of `n(y)o͞oˈmänik` there should not be a problem. I just tested the pronunciations and Siri got it right every time.

Comment: Do you pronounce the two words significantly differently?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to add "mnemonic" to your contacts, add a phonetic name, and set it to something like "nimonic". It's kind of a messy workaround though because then you have a useless contact that's just for a word. So I wouldn't be surprised if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you often dictate other items, that improves how Siri interprets your sounds.  And if you make corrections to misinterpretations, that also improves future interpretations.